# how to make search a text on the terminal directly

Tags: terminal, search

I have a program that outputs some data to the terminal (via printf() ). Is it possible search a text on the outputed text on the terminal **directly**?

It is possible to do search by directing the texts into a file then make search on it then output the result to the terminal, but it is not what I am asking.

EDIT: what I meant by "search": 
I wonder if it is possible to search a text, for example how can I search `libgnome-desktop` on the below terminal output?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a terminal that supports this, or a way to do it in your current terminal? `rxvt` has this

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: I would like to know if a terminal (especially ubuntu's terminal) has such functionality to search a text. If it is the case, how can I do it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the terminal multiplexer `tmux` to run your program in any terminal. Then you can search through the window entering copy mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd>, and use emacs (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>) or vi (<kbd>/</kbd>) keywords to search for a string depending on whether emacs or vi mode is selected.

The keys available to exit copy mode are <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> for different versions of `tmux`.

Alternatively, some terminals support searching the window buffer, like urxvt with the `searchable-scrollback` Perl extension.

Answer (score 4):

If you were using *screen*, then you could go to copy mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>  <kbd>[</kbd> and then type:
`?libgnome-desktop`
To keep searching for more instances press <kbd>n</kbd> for next and <kbd>N</kbd> for previous instance of searched string.
To exit copy mode press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Additionally with *screen* you could press <kbd>space</kbd> when in copy mode to start highlighting text and press <kbd>space</kbd> again to copy that highlighted text. This could be pasted at the prompt or anywhere else on the terminal input with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd>.

Comment: See also `C-A h` to dump the current screen into a file and `C-A : hardcopy -h` to also include the scroll buffer in that dump.

Answer (score 0):

By `search` you mean what? `find`, `grep` or something else?

You *can* put the output of your printf as an argument to another command via the `$()` syntax

```
grep "$(printf "%s" 'foo')" file
```