# search text on the terminal output

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, gnome-terminal

I am running an application with command `$ grails run-app` which prints log in terminal like below.

[image: search_text_terminal]

What I want is search a particular text (say `user authorities`) in this log so that I can verify further. One way using Logging Apis to write in text file but I want to search it in a terminal at the moment.

I found similar question at [how to make search a text on the terminal directly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86205/17781) which suggests `screen` command, but I have no idea how `screen` works in this case. 
I tried 
`$ screen grails run-app` 
but couldn't move ahead.

I can see screen lists with

```
prayag@prayag:~/zlab/nioc2egdelonk$ screen -list
There is a screen on:
    8076.pts-2.prayag   (10/06/2013 12:13:25 PM)    (Attached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-prayag.
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd> (default `screen` command prefix), <kbd>[</kbd> (enter `copy` mode) followed by `?SEARCH_TEXT` seems to work. Press <kbd>n</kbd> to go to the next occurrence. From there, you can copy words, lines, regions, etc to dump into files or paste later on (with <kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: I cannot do this. So you need to press 3 keys at once? ctrl, a, [?

Comment: use `shift+ctrl+f`

Comment: @Ja8zyjits where did you find such shortcut?

Comment: @Rodrigo check [terminator](https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted.html#search-the-buffer).
I should have made this an answer. Oh, i didnt have enough karma to post answer back then.

Comment: Does this not only work with the `screen` utility?

Comment: This command worked on `Terminator`

Answer (score 37):

If you use **Konsole** (KDE terminal emulator), you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. This might work also in other (Linux) terminal emulators; it has been confirmed to work in GNOME Terminal, the Xfce terminal, Alacritty, and Terminator.

Comment: @Augustin where did you find such shortcut?

Comment: @Rodrigo: See the Konsole Handbook: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/konsole/konsole/commandreference.html#edit-menu.

Alternatively, if you have Konsole on your machine, have a look in the Edit menu – the keyboard shortcut should be listed next to the Find... entry.

Comment: Working for Mobaxterm[Windows] ... Thanks mate

Answer (score 13):

You can use `grep` after the `grails` command: `grails run-app | grep "user authorities"`. However, you will have to re-run your command.

Comment: This answer shouldn't be voted down, its absolutely correct.

Comment: While correct, it's more useful to have something one can do *after* the output has already been printed.

Comment: @Baron I'm even pretty sure that the asker meant to imply that the command is already running, so this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

Redirect output of your command to vim-editor: 
`grails run-app | vim -`

Several tips for search using Vim:

- type `/` then enter your search string `user authorities`
- type `:set hlsearch` to highlight search results
- type `n` to search forward or `Shift+n` to search backward
- remember you're in editor now, so if you did some changes accidentally you can revert, just press `ESC` once to exit edit-mode, then press `u` to undo one edit
- type `:q!` to exit Vim and discard your search results
- you can do whatever you want :-D http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki

Answer (score 3):

Redirect the output to pipe and send it to a `grep` command:

```
grails run-app | grep user authorities
```

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to search in terminal.

Got this from the comment above by @Ja8zyjits.

This worked for me.