# Search text in command output on a PuTTY terminal

Tags: terminal, search, putty

I would like to know how to search particular text on the terminal. If I do `cat` of log files, I would like to find certain words like job or summary so that I don't have to read through the entire log file.

I know there have been a similar [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93783/search-text-on-the-terminal-output) about this. The answer from that post is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> `<text>` which doesn't seem to work for me.  When I press that I get a message `No bracket in top line (press Return)` or If I press those keys together I get the message `ESC`.

It there a way to do this with PuTTY? Alternatively, is there a generic way to search for text in the output of commands?

Comment: It helps if you tell us which terminal emulator you're using.

Comment: I am using putty to access remote linux machines..

Comment: What are the commands you're looking to search output from? Just general commands or is there a log file that a server/service is writing messages to that you want to search through?

Comment: `konsole` supports this with ctrl+shift+f

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> is meant for use within the application screen (an app for multiplexing consoles).

#### less

Generally the easiest method to do this is to use tools such as `less` and to pipe the output from whatever application is generating the messages on the console, and search within the application `less`. You can do so using the forward slash (`/`) followed by whatever string you're searching for. Hit return to execute the search.

#### Example

```
$ less filename.log

...then in less, type a forward slash followed by string to search, foo
```

#### grep

In the same vain as above with using `less`, you can also use tools such as `tail` to print the lats few lines of a applications log file messages, and also use `grep` to search for only lines that contain a matching string/pattern.

```
$ grep "somestring" filename.log
```

Comment: I didnt quite get it. After I do cat filename.log | less how can I find particular text from the whole screen, if at all its possible.

Comment: @Ashwin - you can just do `less filename.log` and then use the forward slash key to begin search mode, type a string such as `foo`, and hit return to search. You can keep repeating it by hitting the `n` key.

Comment: Cool this is what I was looking for. I can find it by executing     cat filename.log | grep Summary or less filename

Comment: @Ashwin - glad it worked for you, see my updates, for shorter versions of using both tools so you can skip having to use `cat`.

Comment: how to search for next number 2 search item(for ex second "error" in file)

Comment: @MahenderY - if you have follow up questions please ask them on the main site and reference this Q&A within them.

Answer (score 10):

You can also right click the title bar at the top of the window and select Copy All to Clipboard, then paste into a text editor and use that to search.